# Preserving registers when using inline ASM in XC16

Tags: assembly, inline, pic

I'm working with a PIC24F in C, and need to use some inline assembler. In some parts I need to use some registers (W1 to W3). Do I must preserve the old values, or will the compiler presumes that they have been modified after the **asm** directive?

Thanks.

Comment: Isn't C30 a variation of gcc?  If so, then if you use extended asm, you inform the compiler about which registers get used via the parameters/constraints.  If you are using basic asm (ie no parameters), you must preserve the registers.

Comment: It is and yes it has this syntax. Which is in the C30 manual btw.